# nodejs smtp-server Email gets sent but not received

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const SMTPServer = require("smtp-server").SMTPServer;

const server = new SMTPServer({
    onAuth(auth, session, callback) {
        if (auth.username !== "test" || auth.password !== "password") {
            return callback(new Error("Invalid username or password"));
        }
        console.log(mailOptions.text);
        callback(null, {
            user: "test"

        }); // where 123 is the user id or similar property
    }
});

server.on("error", err => {
    console.log("Error %s", err.message);
});

server.listen(26);


var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "MYDOMAINNAME/IP",
    port: 26,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: "test",
        pass: "password"
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: '"MYSITENAME"<info@MYDOMAIN.com>',
    to: 'ADRESS@TLD.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("sendmail" + error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

Output is:
That was easy!
Email sent: 250 OK: message queued

i just want to send a mail with an input variable as text from my domainname to an normal gmail address;
the mail doesent get received by the gmail/ or any other adress; checked the spam folder;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might simply be **queuing** the email in your instance of `smtp-server` and not actually **sending** it.

The [documentation for `smtp-server`](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/) begins with a note about how this module does not actually send emails by itself:

> This module does not make any email deliveries by itself. `smtp-server` allows you to listen on ports 25/24/465/587 etc. using SMTP or LMTP protocol and that’s it. Your own application is responsible of accepting and delivering the message to destination.

You will need to use the [SMTP client module `smtp-connection`](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-connection/) in conjunction with your SMTP server to send the email.

You can see where the "250 OK: message queued" response is coming from at [this line](https://github.com/nodemailer/smtp-server/blob/c34579adf1064dbf615c8628fa93090da68bd4ac/lib/smtp-connection.js#L1272) in the server module's code.

Answer (score 5):

For who came with this same issue but using the Nodemailer's `transporter` way, I solved this issue adding the `name` of the server into the transporter object.

```js
    const transportObj = {
      name: credentials.host, // in my case, the host and the name are the same
      host: credentials.host,
      port: credentials.port,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
          user: credentials.user,
          pass: credentials.pass
      },
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transportObj)

transporter.sendMail(...)
```

This solution was related [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/677)

Answer (score -1):

My requirement is not to use a third party email provider to send and receive email from known customers. Create a node-express route called send,

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded());
server.use(cookieParser());

server.post('/send', function(req, res){
    try {
        var message = {
            from: '<' + req.body.from + '>',
            to: '<' + req.body.to + '>',
            subject: req.body.subject,
            text: req.body.message,
            html: req.body.html
        };

        var email = req.body.to;

        const dns = require('dns');
        const domain = email.split('@')[1]; 
        // lookup for any MX domains for the recipient?
        dns.resolve(domain, 'MX', function(err, addresses) {
            if (err) {
                res.on({status: 'error', message: 'No MX record exists, so email is invalid.'});
            } else if (addresses && addresses.length > 0) {      
                // use the first MX domain in the list
                const toExchange = addresses[0].exchange;

                const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
                const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    port: 25,
                    host: toExchange,
                    logger: true,
                    debug: true,
                });

               
                transporter.sendMail(message, function(err, info){
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({status: 'error', message: err});
                    } else {
                        res.json({status: 'success', info: info});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch(error) {
        res.json({status: 'error', message: error});
    }
});
```

To accept incoming emails, use the node-mailin. You will need to configure your DNS for your incoming mail server. A good YouTube video is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o66UFsodUYo, the rDNS (reverse DNS) configuration can be resolved by setting the banner on the SMTP Server options as your public host name, which can be identified at https://www.whoismyisp.org/