# nodemailer not sending mail, giving 250 ok

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I've been at this problem all afternoon, all ideas are welcome.
I'm currently running the following example code to locate the issue:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "cpsrv14.misshosting.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: config.email.user,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

// verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: 'christopher.rosenvall@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
}).then(resp => {
    console.log('Message sent: %s', JSON.stringify(resp));
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true
    })
}).catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400)
});
```

});

On request console gives me the following which seems ok to me:

```
Server is ready to take our messages

Message sent: {"accepted":["christopher.rosenvall@gmail.com"],"rejected":
[],"envelopeTime":84,"messageTime":403,"messageSize":603,"response":"250 OK id=1iFhm4-0004WG-
NM","envelope":{"from":"foo@example.com","to":["christopher.rosenvall@gmail.com"]},"messageId":"
<7f8f8aab-f900-1e8e-2cde-3da5ad2687ba@example.com>"}

GET / 200 762.254 ms - 16
```

I've tried messing around with running secure and not, with the tls setting and without - doesn't seem to make a difference as long as I can authenticate.

Problem is that the email is never sent, ive tried sending it to a bunch of different email addresses and not a single one has recieved the email.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833249/nodejs-smtp-server-email-gets-sent-but-not-received

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not running my own smtp server. I'm connecting to a 3rd party service. Another odd thing is that its working with the same code in my production environment, only difference is that its running https on a ubuntu server and my localhost dev is http windows.

Comment: Did you find out what solved your problem? I'm also getting `250 ok` but not email is actually being sent. (Using the GMail API.)

Comment: Yes, as I stated in the comment below, I reinstalled the project and suddenly everything was working.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the project and now everything is working, odd.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check if you give from in your option. I faced this problem. in my case, I didn't provide from in the option field. But everything is working after being given from:fromemail@mail.com